# Multithreaded Web Server for Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm developing a multithreaded web server for an android app and I've some problems with a page that uses an external .css file, and a .js file, but only with Google Chrome! With Firefox and Opera the page is rendered fine, with Google Chrome sometimes the .css is loaded, sometimes the .js, sometime both or neither.

This is my app's structure:

**WebServer.java**

```
class WebServer implements Runnable{
protected boolean ON;

public void start(){
            if(!ON){
            ON=true;
            thread=new Thread(this,"WebServer");
            thread.start(); }}

public void run(){
while(ON){
listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket connectionSocket = listenSocket.accept();
Thread t = new Thread(new Client(connectionSocket));
t.start();
listenSocket.close();}
}}
```

**Client.java**

```
class Client implements Runnable {
public void start(){
        thread=new Thread(this,"Client");
        thread.start();}

public void run(){
//parse the request and send a file
}
}
```

**myApp.java**

```
public class myApp extends Activity{

onCreate(){
WebServer ws=new WebServer(8080);
}

onClick(){
...
ws.start();
}}
```

When I click a button on the activity, it call webserver.start(); In my opinion google chrome sends more requests concurrently and there's a problem with threads...
Can you help me?

**[EDIT]**
I had forgotten to write the loop in the run() method in the question

**[EDIT 2]**
I just tried with an other pc, and there are problems also with firefox..

Comment: Move the ServerSocket creation out of the loop. THis won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general misunderstanding of the thread mechanism in your code.

A runnable has to override run. Not start. The run() method of the runnable will be called when the nesting thread will be started. In other words, the start method of your client will never be used, and hope fully, as it would create a thread inside a thread.. not very usefull.

Redesign your webser so that,  :

- it's start method starts a new nesting thread as you did
- it's run method does the following

  - your webserver binds to a port
  - in a loop : accept new connections and start new client thread for each.
  - the loop could be controlled by a boolean flag that you could rise to stop the server (ON would fit, even if the name of this variable doesn't follow [java naming conventions](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html) and is rather poor semanticly speaking)

then each client would, in it's run (no more start method) :

- read data from socket input stream
- reply on socket outputstream
- briefly, implement http protocole.

You could find some java code to inspire you [on the web](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/Webserver/), [some examples are well documented](http://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/matta/Teaching/CS552/F99/proj4/). Also, you could consider using java.nio package that is maybe less effective for a single request but much more effective at handling massive multiple connections. But code is harder.

You should consider reading more about [runnables](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/threads/runnable.html) and also consider reading some stuff about [synchronized](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html) key word to ensure that your web server doesn't start twice a connection for the same client or get confused in case of simultaneous requests.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I think you misunderstood the code. he uses `start()` to start the webserver thread. His code is actually "ok", but he forgot to put the ` accept()` stuff into a loop, so have can accept more than one connection.

Comment: I was talking of start in client class.

Comment: @ZeissS I edited the answer cause I had forgotten to write the while, but my code already had the while.

Comment: @Snicolas I didn't understand if WebServer must implement Runnable, and if it should override start(), like I have done.

Comment: Use the annotation @Override when you override a method, it helps to emphasize overrides. You will see then that your start method is not an overide as there is no method by this name is super class.